# Is there a way to calculate the value of a color component of a pixel (like green) when the other 2 values are given?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let's say I need to calculate an estimate value of G in an RGB pixel whose R=250 and B=120. Is there any specific method for this?

Comment: Any of the 256 possibilities for G are equally valid, unless you know something else about the color of that specific pixel.

Answer (score 0):

i think its dependent of what type of images you have ?
so by this you can create small regression algorithm
input data X  = {R,B}
output data Y = {G}

where you need to convert image data  to one dimensional vector